# Average electrostatic field over a spherical volume due to a point charge inside

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, singularities

When calculating the average electrostatic field over a spherical volume due to a point charge within the volume, how do we account for the electric field arbitrarily close to the point charge? What about directly at the point charge position? the integral is supposed to find the electric field at every volume element,multiply it by the small volume, and sum the results up vectorally, but how is this done when you have singularities at some volume elements?

Comment: The electric field at a point integrates the sum of dq/(r-r') (r hat) evaluating the e.field at a point other than 0,0,0,causes the integral to  not include the singularity since r-r' ≠ 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the space region of integration $V$ into two regions:

1. a sphere centered at the point charge; the sphere is chosen small enough so that it is entirely in the region over which the averaging is done;
2. the rest of the region $V$, where the electric field is finite.

Now integral over the region 1 is zero due to field symmetry, so it is enough to calculate the integral over the region 2.

Comment: This won't work: The field inside the sphere chosen in 1 consist not only of the point charge's field, but of a domain-dependent contribution from the Green function as well. And the latter will not be symmetric and must not be ignored.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for! thanks for the insight

Comment: It's not what you are looking for because it is wrong (unless the charge is at the center of the sphere).

Comment: well if you take the origin to be the position of the charge, the solution will be exactly symmetrical I think @kricheli

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't mention it in the problem setup. Sounded like the charge could be anywhere. And if it is at the origin, we don't need the division in two volumes anyway, we can use the symmetry right away.

Comment: @kricheli there is only one point charge in the question, so total field is just the Coulomb field due to single charge. And if there were more point charges, the method can be easily applied to each partial field.

Comment: Sorry, my head jumped ahead one step, taking the spherical volume to be a domain for a Poisson problem, thus adding a geometry-dependent term to the Green function. ^^ If that's not what @Ahmed Samir is after then your answer is indeed a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The singularity is integrable! The absolute value of the electric field grows as $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and in three dimensions this can be integrated (for example in a spherically symmetric situation in spherical coordinates this cancels with the $4\pi r^2 \text{d}r$ volume element).